# CakePHP 1.3 and table not found after renaming a table and regenerating the model

Tags: cakephp

I renamed a table recently, and tried to regenerate the model. For some reason it keeps saying "Error: Missing database table" for the old table name. I can't seem to get rid of it, I cleared the cache, etc.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most likely you forgot to remove a relationship to that old model.